# Manually control smartphone power current drawing during charge?

Tags: battery-charging, mobile

#### **How can I manually control, how much power the smartphone does draw?**

Sometimes, a smartphone does accidentally consider a charger as much weaker than it actually is. Sometimes, a boost converter/transformer does not help due to clusmy chargers that supply a temporary voltage drop that fools the smartphone into thinking that the charger is weak.

But what is a way for the phone to be manually controlled by the user, how much power to draw?

Example: From an 12W USB charger, I would like to draw out 5V 2A instead of 0.6A.

And yes, I know: **Everything at my own risk.**

Comment: If they suffer from temporary voltage drops then they ARE weak.

Comment: @Finbarr The drop is just temporary. It goes to 4.95V and then back to 5.15V, even using a powerbank that draws out 2A out if 2.4A.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how a phone implements this power adapter detection. Some charging circuits have their own microcontroller and software which you have no access to.

Depending on the phone it might be possible to "let it think" there is a more powerful power adapter connected simply by **shorting** the two USB data lines (usually a white and a green wire) in the charging cable.

There are also other detection mechanisms which work with certain voltages being present on those same data connections.

This all assumes that the 5 V USB voltage is at least somewhat stable. If you decide to use a charger which cannot meet this requirement then all bets are off, you should really use a better power adapter or accept the slow charging.

Answer (score 1):

The charging circuitry in the phone has control and draws what it needs from the power supply.

So are you planning an app to do this.

Comment: No app. I would like to boost charging.